# Where do SBT env variables come from?

Tags: scala, sbt, environment-variables

I'm moving my first steps with Scala (2.12.7) and SBT (1.2.7).
At some point, I want to get secret value from the environment:

```
sys.env("SECRET_TOKEN")
```

The problem is that, in the sbt shell, `SECRET_TOKEN` is not defined, therefore the application crashes.

So:

```
$ export SECRET_TOKEN="xxx"
$ sbt
[... sbt loads]
sbt> run
[ crashes because of the env var not found ]
```

It's like the sbt shell would get only a subset of the current environment.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried:
`SECRET_TOKEN="xxx" sbt`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sbt` (script + launcher) just launches a fancy `java` process, which should inherit the environment variables from the parent process.

Given

```
$ export SECRET_TOKEN="xxx"
```

Both `build.sbt` and your application during `run` should have access to `sys.env("SECRET_TOKEN")`.

In the comment section, Bruno suggested `SECRET_TOKEN="xxx" sbt`, which apparently worked, but I don't know how that's different from `export`.

In any case,

```
object Hello extends App {
  println(sys.env("SECRET_TOKEN"))
}
```

works for me

```
sbt:hello> run
[info] Running Hello
xxx
```